# Thresholding a sensor value

Tags: c++, arduino, average

**Starting position:**
I have connected a  [distance Sensor](https://www.electroschematics.com/hc-sr04-datasheet/) to an Arduino and would like to get the most accurate values for my project.

**My idea:**
  My first idea would be to ignore both the highest and lowest measurement and calculate a more or less representative average in order to work with these "corrected values".

**What I already know:**
I already know how to calculate the average of 10 measurements (or for 3 like in this example):

```
correctedValue: (value1 + value2 + value3) / 3;
```

**What is my problem:** 
My problem is that I don't know, if there exists a library or something like that for solving my "problem". I can't find a useful tutorial or function to achieve my goal and unfortunately have no idea on my own.

Comment: Calculate the maximum and minimum value, and then subtract them from the total of 10 measurements.

Comment: But how can I calculate the min and max???

Comment: Another solution might be to sort the array by size and then simply delete the first and last number in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse the list once keeping track of the index of the largest value and the smallest value you see.  You can do this by first marking the first element (index 0) as both the smallest (`min_index`) and largest (`max_index`).  Then compare the current with that one.  If it's smaller, set the `min_index` to the current.  If it's larger, set `max_index` to the current.

Then traverse the list again, and add the current value to the sum if the index is neither `min_index` or `max_index`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I'm really sorry, but I really am an absolute newbie. You would really be doing me a HUGE favor if you could set an example. Like with this array:

int distanceValues[] = {8, 9, 11, 13, 8, 7, 9, 15, 45, 1}

Comment: @MichaelBrown I added some more detail.  That should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally implement the running average

```
#define FLEVEL 3
#define FIRSTVAL -1

unsigned char getRAverage(unsigned *last, unsigned char newval)
{
    if(*last == -1) 
    {
        *last = newval << FLEVEL;
        return newval;
    }
    *last -= (*last >> FLEVEL);
    *last += newval;
    return *last << FLEVEL;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For everyone else desperate out there, here's my solution. I wrote a simplified version in Python, hoping it would be helpful. Please comment, if something is not right or you can program something more easy.

```
value = [12, 3, 9, 34, 32]

min = value[0]
max = value[0]

if value[1] < min:
    min = value[1]

if value[2] < min:
    min = value[2]

if value[3] < min:
    min = value[3]

if value[4] < min:
    min = value[4]



if value[1] > max:
    max = value[1]

if value[2] > max:
    max = value[2]

if value[3] > max:
    max = value[3]

if value[4] > max:
    max = value[4]


avg = (((value[0] + value[1] + value[2] + value[3] + value[4]) - min) - max) / 3


print(min)
print(max)
print(avg)
```

Output (for this example):

```
3
34
17.666666666666668
```